# Import from Kafka to HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-kafka

I have the following scenario:

Files are uploaded through a web service and need to be parsed and then stored in HBase. What would be the most adequate way to do that?

I was considering to put something like Storm in between the two, but also found options like Flafka.

What approaches exist and what would be the positives/negatives of using them?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different approaches to do your task.
I prefer [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) - you can use scala and it has great Kafka integration out of the box. Instead of Storm you can use [Spark-Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/streaming/) ( Spark extension to build streaming jobs)